# Add a file back to master branch which was deleted in a revert

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have a feature branch(A) which i recently merged with the master(M) branch.
I reverted M back as there were some issues. A couple of files were deleted from master branch in the process and i'm unable to push the changed files back .

i tried git reset *commitId* --hard and git push
the files are still not getting added

Answer (score 0):

If you run `git status` you will see that the files are marked for deletion after the reset, so you also have to checkout the files to restore them:

```
git reset --hard <commitId>
git status
git checkout -- file1 file2....
```